# Visual Studio 2008 c++ Smart Device Platforms

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

Well i wrote a c++ app for a Windows CE device and selected the platform (from the sdk that came with the CD) for it, if i open the project file it says **Platform Name="IEI_PXA270_E205 (ARMV4I)"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9,00"
    Name="BootInstall"
    ProjectGUID="{EBCFC92F-CD0C-4451-8FD0-4C422C5DA8C2}"
    RootNamespace="BootInstall"
    Keyword="Win32Proj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
    <Platforms>
        <Platform
            Name="IEI_PXA270_E205 (ARMV4I)"
        />........
```

now i reinstalled my windows and installed the same sdk but i can't load the project it just says 
"The project consists entirely of configurations that require support for platforms which are not installed on this machine. The project cannot be loaded."

and if i try to create a new project the sdk is not there..

so what am i missing i know where the sdk is located on my local hard drive... is there any way to add a "platform" manualy or some thing... the only thing that has changed that i can think of is that i have visual studio 2010 installed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok had to try i turned UAC off and restarted my pc installed the SDK and tada it works... gotta love UAC...?

Comment: I am getting the same problem in Windows XP which don't have UAC.Any possible solution ?

Comment: @mohan Sorry i have no idea :(, you could try to run the installation in compatibility mode or try to run it as administrator..

Comment: Uninstalling Windows Mobile SDK and re-installing worked for me.